# Android Studio Build failed with an exception Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: java, android, compilation

Console log:

> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   >     'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   >     non-zero exit value 2
> - Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.   at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:43)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
>     Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>     'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>     non-zero exit value 2     at
>     org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:39)
>     at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:66)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:235)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:222)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
>     ... 55 more Caused by:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>     'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>     non-zero exit value 2     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:42)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCode(AndroidBuilder.java:1193)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$convertByteCode$0.call(Unknown
>     Source)   at
>     com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.doTaskAction(Dex.groovy:151)   at
>     com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.this$5$doTaskAction(Dex.groovy)    at
>     com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex$this$5$doTaskAction.callCurrent(Unknown
>     Source)   at
>     com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.taskAction(Dex.groovy:90)  at
>     org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)     ...
>     61 more Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process
>     'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe'' finished
>     with non-zero exit value 2    at
>     org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:40)
>     ... 68 more

build.gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appdomain.appname"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
        compile 'com.google.guava:guava:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
        compile files('libs/gdata-client-1.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/gdata-contacts-3.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/gdata-contacts-meta-3.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/gdata-core-1.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
        compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-1-7-4.jar')
        compile files('libs/recyclerview.jar')
    }
```

Comment: post your buid.gradle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found solution

just change

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
```

also change

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
```

And use Multi-dex property in your build.gradle file like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sendpulse.sendpulse"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    multiDexEnabled true

}
```

then clean project and rebuild

Comment: I have the same problem, I did this and 10 different things I get the error "Local Path doesn't exist". Any ideas?

Comment: did you update your android sdk? update it`s to latest version

Comment: It worked, turns out I was using more than 65k classes(which is the android limit). I had to use multi-dexing. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Do we need to download all the versions of the sdk for development. Suppose your min SDK requirement is 14 and max is latest. sometimes gradle doesnt sync with some version and "R.java" file becomes unavailable.

Comment: Mayank really right! Use  multiDex in your build.gradle file in defaultConfig just add  multiDexEnabled true

Comment: nice job, had to spend several hours till I've stumbled your answer

Comment: Adding multiDexEnabled true did the rick. THanks !

Answer (score 0):

I also had the similar problem. I removed each jar and checked one by one until i found it.
Basically this problem occur due to jar files.
So,try this,
Put your jar files one by one in dependencies and test.You'll easily get the fix.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do a project cleanup. Go to Build->Clean Project and try again
2. If (1) doesn't work, close and restart your compiler.
3. Do a quick check on your Build.Grade file, make sure only the important files are kept, and delete the unused ones.
4. If all else fails, add "multiDexEnabled true" to your app-level Build.Gradle file.

Do this:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.yourcompanyname.yourappname"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```